# Gulp - using ES6 modules in a combined js file?

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to use ES6 modules in my current GULP setup. I've read that this is yet to be supported by browsers or Babel, so there is a need some elaborate setup to [make this work](http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2015/06/26/using-es2015-with-babel-and-browserify/), using things such `Browserify`, `babelify`, `vinyl-source-stream`. (Seems extremely complex setup).

**What I want** is different from examples I had found online. All the examples are with external files being imported, and I really don't want that. I want all the files to be bundled into a **single file**, with all the modules there already. Here's what I have:

My current GULP setup is like this:

```
gulp.task('buildJS', function() {
    var src = [
        './js/dist/app.js',
        './js/dist/templates.js',
        './js/dist/connect.js',
        './js/dist/config.js',
        './js/dist/utilities.js',
        './js/dist/components/*.js',
        './js/dist/pages/**/*.js',
        './js/dist/modals/*.js',
        './js/dist/init.js' // must be last
    ];

    gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(babel({modules:"common"})) // I have no idea what "modules" actually does
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../js/'))

});
```

And this is an example of a component file in `/js/dist/components/`.
There are many files like this, and they are all combined to a single file.

```
module "components/foo" {
    export function render(settings) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

So later in some page controller I would use it:

```
import { render } from "components/foo";
```

---

### Question:

Now that I have a single file, (been transformed using Babel), how can I use the modules via `Import`?

Comment: I assume you want to import a module in the browser, right? ie. not in node

Comment: @pilau - yes browser, only in the browser

Comment: Found out the best way to do it is with [**rollup**](https://github.com/rollup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the end of 2015 I have been using [**rollupjs**](https://rollupjs.org/) in order to create a bundle of ES2015 (ES6) modules, so I could use *import/export* freely in my code.

---

> I've found Rollupjs to be very good and easy to use. The people behind
> it are great people which devote themselves to the project. I've had
> many questions which I had posted on the project's Github issues page
> and I always got answered pretty quickly.

---

#### Setup includes these rollupjs plugins:

1. [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) (basic rollupjs bundler)
2. [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel) (converts ES2015 code to ES5 or earlier, for legacy browsers support)
3. [rollup-plugin-eslint](https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-eslint) (verify the javascript code is valid)
4. [rollup-plugin-uglify](https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-uglify) (minify the code, to make it smaller)
5. [rollup-plugin-progress](https://github.com/jkuri/rollup-plugin-progress) (shows bundle progress in terminal. shows which file being "worked on")
6. [beepbeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/beepbeep) (Make a console beep sound. I use this to inform me of compilaction errors)

---

## Simplified *GULP* setup I'm using:

```
var gulp               = require('gulp'),
    gutil              = require('gulp-util'),
    rollup             = require('rollup').rollup,
    babelRollup        = require('rollup-plugin-babel'),
    eslintRollup       = require('rollup-plugin-eslint'),
    uglifyRollup       = require('rollup-plugin-uglify'),
    rollupProgress     = require('rollup-plugin-progress'),
    beep               = require('beepbeep');

// ESlint 
var eslint_settings = {
    rulePaths: [],
    rules: {
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs" : [2, "smart-tabs"],
        "block-spacing"            : [2, "always"],
        "comma-style"              : [2, "last"],
        "no-debugger"              : [1],
        "no-alert"                 : [2],
        "indent-legacy"            : [1, 4, {"SwitchCase":1}],
        'strict'                   : 0,
        'no-undef'                 : 1
    },
    ecmaFeatures : {
        modules: true,
        sourceType: "module"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion" : 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": false,
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        }
    },
    globals : ['$', '_', 'afterEach', 'assert', 'beforeEach', 'Cookies', 'd3', 'dataLayer', 'describe', 'done', 'expect', 'ga', 'it', 'jQuery', 'sinon'], baseConfig: {
        //parser: 'babel-eslint',
    },
    envs: [
        'browser', 'es6'
    ]
};


// Rollup plugins configuration
function getRollupPlugins( settings = {} ){
    var rollupPlugins = [];

    rollupPlugins.push({
        presets        : [['es2015', {"modules": false}]], //['es2015-rollup'],
        runtimeHelpers : true,
        exclude        : 'node_modules/**',
        plugins        : ["external-helpers"]
    });

    rollupPlugins.push(eslintRollup( Object.assign({throwOnError:true}, eslint_settings) ))

    rollupPlugins.push(rollupProgress({
         clearLine:true // default: true
    }))

    // I would advise Babel to only be used for production output since it greatly slower bundle creation
    if( settings.ENV == 'production' ){
        rollupPlugins.push(uglifyRollup())
        rollupPlugins.push(babelRollup(rollupPlugins__babel));
    }

    return rollupPlugins;
}

var rollupPlugins = getRollupPlugins();

/**
 * a generic Rollup bundle creator
 * @param  {String} outputPath     [where to save the bundle to (must end with /)]
 * @param  {String} outputFileName [bundle file name]
 * @param  {String} entryFile      [rollup entry file to start scanning from]
 * @return {Object}                [Promise]
 */
function rollupBundle(outputPath, outputFileName, entryFile, bundleOptions){
    bundleOptions = bundleOptions || {};
    bundleOptions.plugins = bundleOptions.plugins || rollupPlugins;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        outputFileName += '.js';
        var cache;

        // fs.truncate(outputPath + outputFileName, 0, function() {
        //     gutil.log( gutil.colors.dim.gray('Emptied: '+ outputPath + outputFileName) );
        // });

        rollup({
            entry   : entryFile,
            plugins : bundleOptions.plugins,
            cache   : cache
        })
        .then(function (bundle) {
            var bundleSettings = {
                    format    : bundleOptions.format || 'umd',
                    sourceMap : false,
                    banner    : config.banner
                },
                result = bundle.generate(bundleSettings),
                mapFileName = outputFileName + '.map',
                sourceMappingURL = '\n//# sourceMappingURL='+ mapFileName;

            cache = bundle;

            // if folder does not exists, create it
            if( !fs.existsSync(outputPath) ){
                gutil.log( gutil.colors.black.bgWhite('Creating directory ' + outputPath) );
                fs.mkdirSync(outputPath);
            }

            // save bundle file to disk
            fs.writeFile( outputPath + outputFileName, result.code + (bundleSettings.sourceMap ? sourceMappingURL : ''), function(){
                resolve();
            });

            // save map file to disk
            if( bundleSettings.sourceMap )
                fs.writeFile( outputPath + mapFileName, result.map.toString());
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            beep(1);
            gutil.log( gutil.colors.white.bgRed('Rollup [catch]: ', err.stack) );
            resolve();
        })
    });
}

// This task bundles the main application, using an entry file which itself has many imports, 
// and those imports also has imports.. like a tree branching
gulp.task('bundle-app', ()=>{
    return rollupBundle('../dist/js/', 'app', 'js/dist/app.js', {format:'cjs'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, don't naively concatenate the files. Use browserify to bundle them, with babelify to compile them (via babel). A basic example would look something like this:

```js
browserify('./entry')
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  // ...
```

It's hard to give more specific advice because your use case is so unclear. Do you have a dependency graph that begins at one file, or are you trying to bundle together a bunch of indepdendent modules? Are you trying to run a script to kick off an application, or do you just want to be able to access modules individually?

Based on the example you linked to in your comment you should have something like this:

`components/doughnut.js`

```js
export default function Doughnut (settings = {}) {
  // ...
};

Doughnut.prototype = {}
```

`routes/home.js`

```js
import Doughnut from './components/doughnut';
export default function () {
  var component = new Doughnut();
  $('body').html(component.render());
};
```

Have each module export what you want to be available from any other module. Have each module import whatever it needs from any other module(s). Whatever uses the controller from this example should then do `import home from './routes/home'`; These modules aren't tied to a global variable `App` and can be reused in other applications (as long as you otherwise make them reusable).

> ```
> .pipe(babel({modules:"common"})) // I have no idea what "modules"
> ```

`modules` is a [babel option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/)  that determines what module format it compiles ES6 module syntax to. In this case, CommonJS.

> ```
> module "components/foo" {
> ```

Thanks to your comments I now understand why you have this. You need to eliminate that. Your component file should look something like:

```js
export function render (settings) {
    return ...
}
```

Paired with:

```js
import { render } from "components/foo";
```

Or if you want a default export / import:

```js
export default function render (settings) {
    return ...
}
```

```js
import render from "components/foo";
```

> ```
> import { render } from "components/foo";
> ```

If you're browserifying your modules, you're probably going to need to use relative paths like `./components/foo` or use something else to deal with the paths, like babel's `resolveModuleSource` option.

Comment: Some code "kicks off" the everything, yes. basically there are js files which are "controllers" for pages, who use modules (controllers) like "header", "breadcrumbs".. and I want to convert all those controllers into ES6 modules. currently they are "riding" the App namespace: `App.components.breadcrumbs = function(){...` I want to convert them to independent modules, like in [this example](http://ponyfoo.com/articles/architecture-of-ecmascript-6-modules#concatenation). All the files, and I mean ALL, are combined into one, so everything is accessible from anywhere once the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I thought this is an ES6 import..from some [tutorial](http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2015/06/26/using-es2015-with-babel-and-browserify/) it seems he got it to work

Comment: No, it's not. Where in the tutorial do you see something like `module "components/foo" {`? I dont' find the word `module` in the page at all. ES6 module syntax is all about `import` and `export` declarations.

Comment: ha, I thought that comment was directed to what comes after it and not before. misunderstood you there. well, I thought I should write modules like that from [this example](http://ponyfoo.com/articles/architecture-of-ecmascript-6-modules#concatenation) where they explicitly used the word "module.."

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought about bullet-pointing those for that reason, but it didn't seem worth the trouble. The link you just posted appears to be from 2 years ago. The final ES6 spec was only published a few months ago. In any case, if the point of that construct would've been to support concatenation, it's irrelevant when using browserify to bundle.

Comment: but eventually, even when I use browserify, the functions will still actually be bound to some namespace and theoretically they could be altered. so, I would achieve no better state than where I am now, with my `App.components` scope namespace..

Comment: @vsync Please describe in better detail what specifically you're trying to accomplish by bundling the modules. I can't tell if you just want to bundle the dependencies of an app, or if you want to export each module the bundle so they can be individually `require()`'d by external code, or what.

Comment: I wrote [this example](http://jsbin.com/derihe/2/edit?js,output) of a very basic App which explains things

Comment: @vsync I added an example based on your link. The page controllers will be in the bundle, right?

Comment: Yes they will, everything is

Comment: Ok, so yeah, do it like I illustrated and point browserify at an entry file that has the other modules in its dependency graph. FYI I just fixed an error in my example: the `import` declarations need to be top-level.